# Wordpress https css and js script not loaded,

Tags: wordpress, https, mixed-content

I installed a new version of wordpress on a server web running under https.

I changed the two siteurl and home options value to my https://mysiteweb.com

I added the following value into my wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );

define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL',   'https://mysiteweb.com/wp-content' );

define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content/mydir/plugins' );
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'https://mysiteweb.com/wp-content/mydir/plugins' );
```

Bu I still the same error for all css and javascript file loading:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mysiteweb.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://mysiteweb.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.4.2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by editing wp-config.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: This helped me, I was migrated an existing website app service with wordpress. I am surprised that I need to put such essential setting in the configuration. Locally and on the original server it works without this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Press CRTL + U and check your page source for HTTP, after you found where it's loading the HTTP replace it with HTTPS, usualy the problem is some image or logo not properly loaded / hard coded into HTTP.

Also why did you use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ? rather then just writing your domain.
Possible problem that I see you don't need to use the backslash on last part of the domain.

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com'  );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com' );
```

And you don't need to use the other part's which you defined.

Comment: I replaced WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME with https and I still have the same problem, It's a new wordpress version I touched to anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

I explored the file `wp-config.php` and found:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

### Solution 1:

set `X-Forwarded-Proto` as `https`. If you are using *nginx* the configuration can be:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myblog.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wordpress/;
        proxy_redirect http://wordpress/ https://myblog.com/;
        proxy_set_header Host myblog.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
}
```

### Solution 2:

set directly `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';` to the file `wp-config.php`.